# Determining Whether a Matrix Has At Least One Zero Element

Tags: r, matrix

I'm sure this is trivial - nonetheless, any help would be appreciated.

The problem is simple: given a matrix, I'd like to get `TRUE` if the matrix in question has at least one element equal to zero. So, checking

```
A <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0), nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)

> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1    2    3
[2,]  4    5    0
```

would return `TRUE`, while

```
B <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)

> B
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
```

would return `FALSE`.

Something like

```
if ( A == 0 ) { cat("\nZero detected")}
```

gives a warning. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The warning is generated because you're presenting a vector of logical to `if`, which expects a single value.  `any` is a function to tell if *any* of the logical values are `TRUE`:

```
any(A==0)
## [1] TRUE
any(B==0)
## [1] FALSE
```

There's also a function `all` which determines if *all* of the values in a logical vector are `TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, two good answers but you got there just ahead of Fernando. Many thanks to you both for such quick responses!

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
0 %in% A
```

It should return TRUE or FALSE. It works for NA too:

```
x = matrix(1:24, ncol = 4)
x[3, 3] = NA

NA %in% x 
#TRUE
```